# How to create xsl for best available with best rate?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is the xml

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>1001</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>Available</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>15.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>1001</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>ON-Request</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>10.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>1002</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>ON-Request</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>15.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>1002</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>ON-Request</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>10.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>1003</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>Available</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>15.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>1003</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>Available</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>10.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I need out put like below

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>1001</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>Available</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>15.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>1002</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>ON-Request</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>10.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductCode>1003</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>Available</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>10.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

1. Take only cheap price.
2. If product `<AvailabilityStatus>` is 'Available', take only `Available` otherwise `On-Request`

How i write this in xsl 1.0?

i try like below (i try with document because there is multiple files)

here every thing working fine but not checking the AvailabilityStatus

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
            <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:key name="ServiceByGroup" match="Product" use="ProductCode"/>


            <xsl:template match="Products">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:variable name="msNodes">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('my_file.xml')">
<xsl:sort select="TotalPrice" data-type="number"/>
                            <xsl:sort select="AvailabilityStatus" data-type="text"/>

                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:variable>


                    <Product>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($msNodes)/Product [generate-id() =  generate-id(key('ServiceByGroup', ProductCode)[1])]"/>
                    </Product>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: +1 for adding what you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused about what you mean by having multiple files, when your question only shows one. I am going to assume you only want to apply the XSLT to each file in turn (as opposed to merge them all into one).

You don't need to use the **document** function in this case, if that is the XML file you are applying the XSLT to anyway. (And if the document function is referencing a difference file, then just apply the XSLT to that file directly, as your XSLT is not doing anything with the original file!)

Anyway, isn't the reason it is not working if your sort statements are around the wrong way. You need to be sorting on **AvailabityStatus** first if you want to give priority to "Available" ones first.

Try this XSLT, which doesn't need the **document** function, or the **node-set** extension function

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="ServiceByGroup" match="Product" use="ProductCode"/>

    <xsl:template match="Products">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Product[generate-id() =  generate-id(key('ServiceByGroup', ProductCode)[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Product">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('ServiceByGroup', ProductCode)">
            <xsl:sort select="AvailabilityStatus" data-type="text"/>
            <xsl:sort select="TotalPrice" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following output, which matches the output shown in your question

```
<Products>
   <Product>
        <ProductCode>1001</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>Available</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>15.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
   <Product>
        <ProductCode>1002</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>ON-Request</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>10.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
   <Product>
        <ProductCode>1003</ProductCode>
        <AvailabilityStatus>Available</AvailabilityStatus>
        <TotalPrice>10.000</TotalPrice>
    </Product>
</Products>
```